# NullPointerException on cursor RawQuery - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, cursor, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a db, insert into the db, pull from the db and display the contents (long) to a TextView.

I think I am creating and inserting into the db correctly.  In my `getScore()` method I am getting a NullPointerException.

Any help on code structure is much appreciated as well!  Thank you in advance.

DatabaseHelper.java

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper { 

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Table columns names. 
    private static final String SCORE = "score"; 

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db;
    }

    public long getScore(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + SCORE + " = " + 11 + ";", null);  //Line 45
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);  //Line 39
        long i = 0;
        if(c.getCount() == 0) {
            i = 333;
        } else if (c.getCount() == 1) {
            i = 444;
        } else {
            i = 888;
               /*c.moveToFirst();
               int columnIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SCORE"));
               if(columnIndex != -1) {
                   i = c.getLong(columnIndex);
               } else { 
                   i = 999; 
               }*/
        }
        c.close();
        return i;
    }

    //Insert new record.
    public long insert(long score, int percentage) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SCORE, score);
        values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage);

        return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);
    }

    public synchronized void closeDB(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        if(db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE + " ("
                + RANK + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + SCORE + " LONG,"
                + PERCENTAGE + " INTEGER"
                + ");");
    }
}
```

Highscores.java

```
public class Highscores extends Activity {

    DatabaseHelper dh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    long scores;

    TextView score;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.highscoresmain);

        dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        dh.openDB();
        long x = 11;
        int y = 22;

        TextView score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);        
        TextView r1s = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.r1s);

        dh.insert(x, y);
        scores = dh.getScore(db);  //Line 56            
        score.setText("Score Column - TEST");
        r1s.setText("" + score);

        dh.closeDB(db);
    }
}
```

LogCat output

```
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Highscores}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.getScore(DatabaseHelper.java:39)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at com.example.test.Highscores.onCreate(Highscores.java:56)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
01-03 17:36:01.172: E/AndroidRuntime(1941):     ... 11 more
```

EDIT:  New `getScore()` method.

```
public long getScore() {
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + SCORE + " = " + 11 + ";", null);
    //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT " + SCORE + " FROM " + TABLE + ";", null);
    long i = 0;
    if(c.getCount() == 0) {
        i = 333;
    } else if (c.getCount() == 1) {
        i = 444;
    } else if (c.getCount() == 2) {
        i = 555;
    } else {
        i = 666;
           /*c.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("SCORE"));
           if(columnIndex != -1) {
               i = c.getLong(columnIndex);
           } else { 
               i = 999; 
           }*/
    }
    c.close();
    return i;
}
```

This still returns i with a value of 666.

Comment: What's exactly on `com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.getScore(DatabaseHelper.java:39)`?

Comment: `dh.closeDB(db);` here `db` seems to be `null`.

Comment: @Ameen I commented in my code line 39 of DatabaseHelper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overriding your local `db` value here: `public long getScore(SQLiteDatabase db) { ...` . Remove that parameter and it should work.

Comment: I integrated your suggestion above and it works with no NPE!  I would like to ask one more question now.  When score gets displayed in the TextView, it displays 888.  Why is it not displaying 444?  Wouldn't the count of the cursor be equal to 1?  I also recompiled checking if the count was equal to 2 and it still is going to the last else statement in the method.

Comment: Hmmm did you add the where clause back in? You might be getting all of the table back in your cursor.

Comment: I ammended my opening post with the new ````getScore()```` method.  It returns 666 whether I send in the query that is commented in or the other query that is currently commented out.

Answer (score 2):

The db you are passing to your database class in never initialized and is null. `scores = dh.getScore(db);  //Line 56` the db variable here is a member variable and you should initialize it before passing it to this method.

Comment: Yup! Just caught that myself. +1

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D%29), maybe this is your problem.

> The SQL string must not be ; terminated