# Cursor Index out o fBounds Exception :Index 11 requested, with a size of 11

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

I faced one issue randomly whenever try to get the getSelectedCustomerPhone()  then randomly cursor index out of Bound Exception will appear.
Is there anything wrong with this code?. I could not find the bug.

```
private String getSelectedCustomerPhone() {

        myCursor.moveToPosition(selectedCustPosition);

        String phone = 
               myCursor.getString(myCursor.getColumnIndex("cust_phone"));
        if (phone != null) return phone;
        return "";
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NullPointerException on cursor RawQuery - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14144468/nullpointerexception-on-cursor-rawquery-android)

Comment: `selectedCustPosition` might not be a valid row index. Indexes are zero-based so with a size of 11, valid indexes are 0..10.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `selectedCustPosition` is outside of the cursor range [0, [Cursor.getCount()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getCount()) - 1].  Try understanding why it happens.
As a workaround to prevent the crash, you can add a check

```
if (0 <= selectedCustPosition && selectedCustPosition < myCursor.getCount()) {
   myCursor.moveToPosition(selectedCustPosition);
   // ...
}
```

But this is only a workaround that will more likely return incorrect phone number. Better to understand the real problem: why `selectedCustPosition` is incorrect.